# live updating total num of results while user fills in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

i am currently working a project and the client is asking for a feature which is going to require the help of javascript - which i'm no expert with, i can do basics etc but don't really know where to start with this, on the site there is a form (like an advanced search) and on the right it should show the total number of results, but it needs to keep updating as the form is filled in so as the user goes through filling in the form the total number of results is updated to reflect...

I thought maybe it could be done with ajax, passing along the contents/value of the input, performing a query then passing back the total num of results, but how would it work for every input, isn't that just going to be overkill, i tried to tell the client it would be a strain on the server (which surely it would be) but they seem dead-set on having it...

Any help or techniques would be very useful, or if you have come across something like this before please do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could attach a function to the [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event of each input control that is used in the 'advanced search' to perform the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) call to the server and get the current number of results.

This way the ajax server call will only fire each time an input field is completed and the focus moves elsewhere.

Of course if you have many fields this will result in a call each time a field is completed or amended and the focus is moved. It would also be wise to ensure that the field value has changed before making the ajax call. Something along the lines of:

```
var tempVal = "";

// Each field that is used in the advanced search will need to have the
// advancedSearchInput class    

$('.advancedSearchInput').focus(function() {
   tempVal = $(this).val();
});

$('.advancedSearchInput').blur(function() {
   if($(this).val() == tempVal) {
      // Get advanced search values and make ajax call
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid this sort of thing as like you say it can be strain on the server. Here are few things I do to help reduce this risk:

- Only perform the search/count when the user has entered at least 3 characters
- Cache search terms and their resultant count in a memory store like [Redis](http://redis.io) or memcached
- Use MySQL full-text searching if you are running a MySQL DB

Another option is to present fuzzy numbers. So you get the total number of records when the page loads and then as the user types you randomly take a chunk off the total. Once the users term is more specific or they actually click the submit button you can execute actual Ajax requests to get the actual count.

So the user would see something like:

**Search**: ""
**Response**: `There are about 3097 records relevant to your search`

**Search**: "Ap"
**Response**: `There are about 1567 records relevant to your search`

**Search**: "Apple"
*issues ajax request*
**Response**: `There are 542 records relevant to your search`

Comment: Fuzzy numbers seems like a good solution, how would you go about actually implementing it into the form though, attach an ajax function to each input/select etc ?